# Clear JPanel or JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawing

Without using `super.paintComponent(g);` can i still clear my Jpanel or Jframe Screen? I have some shapes drawn on JPanel and i want to clear all the drawing when user presses the right click without Using this method. or i say is there any alternate of `super.paintCompenent(g)`;method or method like `clrscr();` In Java.

**EDIT**

```
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            super.paintComponents(null); //i want to use this method here?? how can i? 
            if(e.isPopupTrigger())
            {
                s=e.getX();
                as=e.getY();
              try {
                    Thread.sleep(10L);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(animate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
        p.repaint();
            }
        }
```

i am painting the shape like this

```
public class mypanel extends JPanel {

   @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

       super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g ;

        Color[] c = {Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, 
                 Color.MAGENTA, Color.WHITE, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK};
    for(int i=0; i<8; ++i){
        g2.setColor(c[i]);
        int start_angle=i*45;
    g2.fillArc(mx-100, my-100, 200, 200, start_angle,45);



    }
```

Comment: you can call repaint and stop calling Graphics primitives. If you have components, then simply call removeAll()

Comment: @Jeffrey code for what?? its too lengthy.

Comment: @james post an SSCCE then: http://sscce.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mre solution is actually a good idea, but you may have issues if another repaint comes in (because you move the JFrame, because you resize it, because another window comes on top of it and then leavs, etc...)

Alternatively, you can have something like this to make the change permanent:

```
public class mypanel extends JPanel {

    private boolean draw = true;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (draw) {
            Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g ;

            Color[] c = {Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, 
                     Color.MAGENTA, Color.WHITE, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK};
            for(int i=0; i<8; ++i){
                g2.setColor(c[i]);
            int start_angle=i*45;
            g2.fillArc(mx-100, my-100, 200, 200, start_angle,45);
        }
    }

    public void setDraw(boolean draw) {
        this.draw = draw;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

And then you can just draw or not in your JPanel simlpy by calling mypanel.setDraw(boolean)

Comment: Did you missed the limits `{}` after `if (draw)` by mistake :-), That's exactly what i thought of +1 for this :-) Nice Answer :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw yup, I sure did. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [`Graphics#clearRect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) is what you're looking for?

Comment: +1, I will go with this answer. The OP and simply put a `boolean variable`, somewhere, make it true at `mousePressed(...)`, and do what  you told in your answer, by checking it inside `paintComponent(...)` method, else do the normal drawing as usual :-)